# PostgreSQL COPY FROM issue

Tags: postgresql, heidisql

```sql
DROP table if exists legislators;

CREATE table legislators
(
...
)
;

COPY legislators 
FROM 'C:\data\legislators.csv'
DELIMITER ',' -- It is written in different line from `FROM` clause but it raises ERROR.
CSV HEADER;
```

I am trying to import CSV file to PostgreSQL on HeidiSQL v11. When I execute a query written in muliple lines as above, it raises an error:

**`ERROR: syntax error at or near "CSV" LINE 1: CSV HEADER;`**

However, I found that if I write a `FROM` clause and `DELIMITER ','` in a single line together as below, it works well.

```
COPY legislators 
FROM 'C:\data\legislators.csv' DELIMITER ',' -- These FROM and DELIMITER should be the same line to work 
CSV HEADER;
```

I know SQL basically ignores whitespace, but I am confused why this happens.

It would be very appreciate someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: You could try using the newer style of specifying the options `WITH` as : `...FROM 'C:\data\legislators.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMITER ',')`. FYI, `DELIMITER ','` is redundant for `CSV` as that is the default delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because HeidiSQL is not very smart about parsing PostgreSQL lines and gets confused. It executed the statement as two statements, which causes the error.

Use a different client with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not expect that HeidiSQL has the drawback.